# Inertial frame definition in Rindler Introduction to STR vs Landau' & Lifshitz Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, inertial-frames, definition, galilean-relativity

Juxtaposing Rindler's Introduction to STR (page 7) vs Landau's Mechanics (page 5) inertial frame definition,I get that rindler assumes frame moving uniformly w.r.t inertial frame as an inertial frame which is not the case with landau. and I think axiomatizing is the better or in fact the only approach to answer the question why frames moving uniformly w.r.t inertial frame is an inertial frame?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481321/2451

Comment: Related post:https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3193/